# Select a row from a table within a date range

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

is it possible to sellect a row from a table like so

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? FROM date 2015-02-17 08:12:54 TO date 2015-02-17 09:12:54
```

Because I have a login table, and I want to check to make sure they're not bruteforcing.

Is that possible?

Comment: It sure is possible. One way is to use BETWEEN http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between they've examples in there you can look at. However, there are other ways to go about it.

Comment: Just looking at your syntax, you obviously cannot have to two "FROM" in the same select.  I assume you have a column with a date data type. You need to use that date column.

Comment: @kenkoehler I'm sure that's pseudo-code; *it's gotta be*. Otherwise, yep, you're entirely correct.

Comment: Yeah was just a code to get my point. I shall use between thank you.

Comment: Something like this too `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND date_col1 >= '2015-02-17 08:12:54' AND date_col2 <= '2015-02-17 09:12:54'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.username = ? AND
      u.date BETWEEN '2015-02-17 08:12:54' AND '2015-02-17 09:12:54'
```

If you have a large table, this query can take advantage of an index on `users(username, date)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible

The smaller date has to be listed first 
Example

WHERE  BETWEEN '12/19/2012'  AND '1/17/2013'